# bootstrap 3.1 modal into a form

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3.1

I have a problem with modal into a form ...

If I put my modal code into the form like that :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="pro_dossier_location_maj.php" role="form" method="post">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

My problem : if I click on the modal button, the modal is opened but the form is immediately submitted !

I think that's a bug of the new version 3.1 of Bootstrap because I don't have this problem with the 3.03 version.

An example :
http://jsbin.com/icObUHIT/1/
In this example, we see that the modal is open and immediately the form code is submitted.

With the same example but with Bootstrap version 2. the modal is open and wait :
http://jsbin.com/icObUHIT/2/

The form has lot of input. In this form I have several buttons and for each buttons I have modal window to confirm by the user if he wantes really to delete, duplicate, print etc ...

So the structure of the code is not à form in a modal but a form with severals modals inside.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you very much

Comment: In your example I don't see the page getting submitted. It works fine. Please check again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the form inside the modal.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" action="pro_dossier_location_maj.php" role="form" method="post">
                      ...
                  </form>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. The trick, I found, was to change the "button" that launches the modal to be a 'link' instead of a button `<a href...>` vs `<button...>` Here's the solution I have found:

```
<form ..... >

     <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     Open Modal
    </a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Give your story a title!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title">Enter Title:</label>
              <input type="type" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Story Title">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button-->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Story</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I'm using the modal to submit my form, so I left the `save story` button as a button, so it would submit. I think if you don't want it to submit, you may have to change it.

Comment: Actually, your real problem was that `button`s have the default `type` of `submit`.  You could have alternately fixed your problem by simply setting the button's `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

The gotcha is that the button to open the modal must be type="button"

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>
```